# Array of sprites doesnt respond to touch move

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, cocos2d-iphone

I was implementing a way to move my sprites, I put an array where I put all my sprites, and to that array I want to give the action of moving with the touch. But when I run it, nothing happens:

```
-(void)onEnter
{
    [super onEnter];
    self.isTouchEnabled = YES;
}

- (void)ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *myTouch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [myTouch locationInView:[myTouch view]];
    location = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:location];

    mSpriteOnHand = nil;

    for(CCSprite *cloth in mSpriteArray)
    {
        if(CGRectContainsPoint([cloth boundingBox], location))
        {
            mSpriteOnHand = cloth;
            break;
        }
    }
}


- (void)ccTouchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView: [touch view]];
    location = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:location];

    if(mSpriteOnHand)
        mSpriteOnHand.position = location;

}

- (void)ccTouchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    mSpriteOnHand = nil;
}

-(void)onExit
{
    [mSpriteArray release];
    mSpriteArray = nil;
    [super onExit];
}
```

Is there something wrong? I think the problem is on the Touch Began, but Im not sure...

EDIT:

My sprites are not responding, but the methods seems to be ok. Here is my init:

```
-(id) init
{
    if( (self=[super init]) )
    {
        CGSize winSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];
        CCSprite * backGround = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"background_ipad.png"];
        backGround.position = ccp(winSize.width/2, winSize.height/2);
        [self addChild:backGround z:0];

        cloth1 = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"clothe_1.png"];
        cloth1.position = ccp(380, 500);
        [self addChild:cloth1 z:1];

        cloth2 = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"clothe_2.png"];
        cloth2.position = ccp(530, 500);
        [self addChild:cloth2 z:2];

        cloth3 = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"clothe_3.png"];
        cloth3.position = ccp(700, 500);
        [self addChild:cloth3 z:3];

        cloth4 = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"clothe_4.png"];
        cloth4.position = ccp(380, 270);
        [self addChild:cloth4 z:4];

        cloth5 = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"clothe_5.png"];
        cloth5.position = ccp(530, 270);
        [self addChild:cloth5 z:5];

        cloth6 = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"clothe_6.png"];
        cloth6.position = ccp(700, 270);
        [self addChild:cloth6 z:6];

        [mSpriteArray addObject: cloth1];
        [mSpriteArray addObject: cloth2];
        [mSpriteArray addObject: cloth3];
        [mSpriteArray addObject: cloth4];
        [mSpriteArray addObject: cloth5];
        [mSpriteArray addObject: cloth6];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: Have you tested whether the Touch events are firing at all? Are the touch and sprite coordinates being calculated for the same node space?

Comment: I tested  it, and it doesnt. I dont know, how do I check that?

Comment: If the touch event isn't firing at all, some things to check might be, are we sure the node has been added to the scene, is the node a CCLayer (other nodes cannot have touch enabled by simply setting isTouchEnabled), are we sure there is not another node swallowing the touches or something like that before this node gets a chance to respond to the touch?

Comment: I'm checking that but there is nothing at all... If you need more code, just ask it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this derives from CCSprite, it wont work. In such case, use :

```
-(void) onEnter {
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector].touchDispatcher addStandardDelegate:self priority:0];
    [super onEnter];
} 

-(void) onExit {
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector].touchDispatcher removeDelegate:self];
    [super onExit];
}
```

EDIT 1 :

```
CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:[touch view]];
CGPoint convertedLocation = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:location];

MPLOG(@"Touch at location %@", NSStringFromCGPoint(convertedLocation));
```

EDIT 2 :

in init :

```
mSpriteArray = [[NSMutableArray array] retain]; // without ARC
```

and in dealloc :

```
-(void) dealloc {
    [mSpritesArray release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

am not sufficient 'ARC' savvy to suggest anything. Also, depending on what 'self' is, ie what children you have in there, you may not need an array, since every CCNode already has one already.  As follows:

```
for (CCSprite* cloth in self.children) {        
    if(CGRectContainsPoint([cloth boundingBox], location))
        {
            mSpriteOnHand = cloth;
            break;
        }
}
```

EDIT 3 : exclude background:

an iVar:

```
int tag:UNIQUE_TAG_FOR_BACKGROUND;
```

in init :

```
UNIQUE_TAG_FOR_BACKGROUND = 4367;  // pick a number 
[self addChild:backGround z:0 tag:UNIQUE_TAG_FOR_BACKGROUND];
```

in loop:

```
for (CCSprite* cloth in self.children) { 
    if(cloth.tag == UNIQUE_TAG_FOR_BACKGROUND) continue;       
    if(CGRectContainsPoint([cloth boundingBox], location))
        {
            mSpriteOnHand = cloth;
            break;
        }
}
```

Comment: Nope, still nothing happened.

Comment: Logging is your friend : first confirm that you are getting the ccTouchesBegan event. If yes, then figure out the geometry. I am not certain your 'location' in ccToucheMoved will give you what you want. See my edit.

Comment: I put some logs and find out that the began is recognized, then, when i click the sprite and move it it recognize the movement! But the sprites is not responding...

Comment: I have just edited and added my INIT method, maybe there is a mistake.

Comment: I dont see mSpriteArray being initialized.

Comment: Great job! I can move them, but when trying to move them, the background started moving, my face was like wtf?

Comment: hahaha ... sorry i had not seen that you had a background sprite in the object. Well, you can use your array after all, or find another handy cocos2d way to achieve your purpose. happy coding :)

Comment: Before you go, do you know how to not move the background? u.u

Comment: Yes, but i dont know your app nor what this class is and what your final intent is, so design advice may be pointless. One way to do this is to exclude background from the search by giving it a unique tag. (see edit)

Comment: I will see it, thank you so much really, very nice coding! :D